# Using a diff on a document containing HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, diff

I'm in the brainstorming process for a system that will be used to write and edit documents (think Google Docs, but without realtime collaboration). I will be using a WYSIWYG editor, so the documents will contain HTML.

Editors will make changes to the documents, and the original user should see those revisions and make the changes manually.

How can I use a diff system when HTML tags are involved? I'd like the revisions to display any changes to formatting, so for instance if something was bolded, then it should pick up on that change. It should also make content changes visible like a normal diff.

If I were to use a regular diff system, then it would see the HTML as regular text, which is obviously not the case. Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: If you use a regular diff system and it see's HTML as regular text, why wouldn't that work? If you bold something, the regular diff is going to see extra text for the bold tags. Same if you remove HTML tags.

Comment: do the actual comparison on the HTML, but when you show side by side, render the html.  Highlight the lines with changes, as done in a regular diff tool. should work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best OSS library I've worked with for HTML diffing is [DaisyDiff](http://code.google.com/p/daisydiff/) ([PHP Version](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Visual_Diff)).

That noted, diffing HTML, or XML for that matter, is a troublesome beast. If you can simplify the data to be compared by doing some pre-processing before passing to a diffing algorithm you may get better results. For instance, if you really only use things like `<p>`, `<b>`, `<i>` tags tokenize them and use a differencing algorithm such as [diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) or [GNU Diff](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/). Then replace those tokens afterward. See this [diff-match-patch wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/wiki/Plaintext) for some thoughts on this.

Comment: DaisyDiff is exactly what I'm looking for. That's a huge help, thanks orangepips. There are a few things that I'll need to modify (for instance, DaisyDiff doesn't note paragraph tag changes), but it should be a great place to start.

Comment: Note: to overcome the lack of paragraph tag change detection, I am just automatically adding a ↵ symbol to the end of the paragraphs before diffing. It will then pick up on split/merged paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

You're in for a world of pain if you try to create this from scratch. I'd try to pick up an off-the-shelf solution - google "HTML diffing," you'll see some vendors.

One approach you might take is extracting the text (strip tags) and compare the non-tagged versions. This is very easy to do, but doesn't accomplish what you want fully - it won't compare formatting between revisions.